How to obtain a series solution to ODE using the Frobenius method
In this question, I hope to obtain the series solution R[r] in the following ODE using Frobenius method,
eqrad:= -(rf + rg - (2 rf rg)/r + 2  r  \[Lambda] - 
        2  rf  \[Lambda] - 2  r^3  \[Omega]^2)  R[
      r] + (-2  rf  rg + r  (rf + rg))  Derivative[1][R][r] + 
    2 r  (r - rf)  (r - rg)  (R^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] // Simplify;

The following content is my attempt but only for the case $r_g=r_h$. When $r_g=r_h$, the series solution R[r] at $r\rightarrow r_h$ can be solved by following codes:
Clear["`*"]
rg = rh;
eqrad := -(rh + rg - (2  rh  rg)/r + 2  r  \[Lambda] - 
        2  rh  \[Lambda] - 2  r^3  \[Omega]^2)  R[
      r] + (-2  rh  rg + r  (rh + rg))  Derivative[1][R][r] + 
    2 r  (r - rh)  (r - rg)  (R^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] // Simplify;
R[r_] = r^AI*
   Exp[BI*r]*(1 + a1/r + a2/
     r^2(* + ... *)); (*use this ansatz to find the asymptotic \
solution*)
Series[eqrad/(r^AI*Exp[BI*r]), {r, \[Infinity], -2}] // FullSimplify
(* From the r^3 term we find BI, from the r^2 term we find AI:  *)
Solve[{2  (BI^2 + \[Omega]^2) == 
    0, (4  AI  BI - 4  BI^2  rh + 2  a1  (BI^2 + \[Omega]^2)) == 
    0}, {BI, AI}] // FullSimplify

On the other hand, when $r_g=r_h$, the series solution R[r] at $r\rightarrow \infty$ can be solved by following codes:
eqrad := -(rh + rg - (2  rh  rg)/r + 2  r  \[Lambda] - 
        2  rh  \[Lambda] - 2  r^3  \[Omega]^2)  R[
      r] + (-2  rh  rg + r  (rh + rg))  Derivative[1][R][r] + 
    2 r  (r - rh)  (r - rg)  (R^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] // Simplify;
R[r_] = (r - rh)^
   AH*(1 + a1*(r - rh) + 
     a2*(r - rh)^2(* + ... *));(*use this ansatz to find the \
asymptotic solution*)
Series[eqrad/(r - rh)^AH, {r, rh, 0}] // FullSimplify
(* From the zeroth order term, we find AH *)
Solve[{2  rh  (AH^2 + rh^2  \[Omega]^2) == 0}, AH] // FullSimplify

Finally, the series solution for R[r] can be obtained:
BI = I  \[Omega]; AI = I  rh  \[Omega]; AH = -I  rh  \[Omega];
R1[r] -> (r^(AI - AH))*((r - rh)^AH) Exp[BI*(r - rh)]*f[r](*f[
  r]= \[CapitalSigma] Subscript[a, n]((r-rf)/r)^n*)

The following picture is the case for $r_h=r_g=1$:

Therefore, my question is how to obtain the series solution R[r] when $r_g \neq  r_h$. I would be grateful if you could provide some tips and solutions.
Thanks again for all your help!

The ansatz of series solution R[r] are often related to boundary conditions. These boundary conditions can be thought of as pure incident waves $\exp^{-i \omega r_}$ at the horizon and pure outgoing waves $\exp^{i \omega r_}$ at infinity. Where, $r_$ is the tortoise coordinates. Here, $r_ = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{r-rh}{r}\frac{r-rg}{r}}}dr$.

Have  you tried AsymptoticDSolveValue?

see find-a-frobenius-approximation-asymptoticdsolvevalue and FrobeniusDSolveFormula and FrobeniusDSolve for examples.

Thanks for these comments and help. After trying AsymptoticDSolveValue, I find that it seems to only give regular series solution. However, in my problem, the ansatz of $R[r]$ needs to be given with the help of tortoise coordinate $r_*$, then the coefficient of $R[r]$ is determined step by step. A special case is the picture in my question, which uses formulas 3.4.67 and 3.4.68 to determine $R[r]$ of 3.4.66. So, it doesn't seem to be done in one step with AsymptoticDSolveValue. How to construct a suitable $R[r]$ through tortoise coordinate when $r_g \neq r_h$ remains a problem.
